# Concat arguments

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I have a couple of questions in the following line ARM template code

```
"variables": {
    "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
    "SharedTemplateSAS": "[concat('?',split(deployment().properties.templateLink.uri,'?')[1])]",
```

What is the argument '?' going to be ?
Is the properties.templateLink.uri dependent on the TemplateLink URI? (I want to use templatespec and refer to linked templates by relative path)

Finally, what is the line doing exactly?

Comment: Please check tag descriptions when applying them; I've removed [tag:arm] which is for the ARM CPU architecture.  Did you mean [tag:azure-resource-manager]?

Answer (score 0):

> "SharedTemplateSAS":
> "[concat('?',split(deployment().properties.templateLink.uri,'?')[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates?tabs=azure-powershell#securing-an-external-template))]",

> What is the argument '?' going to be ? Is the
> properties.templateLink.uri dependent on the TemplateLink URI? (I want
> to use templatespec and refer to linked templates by relative path)

Looking at the sample examples in the [git Hub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-json-samples/blob/master/azure-resource-manager/linkedtemplates/static-public-ip.json) for [linked templates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-json-samples/blob/master/azure-resource-manager/linkedtemplates/static-public-ip-parent.json), the template link uri property is used in the linked templates inorder to get the uri of the childtemplate which contains the information about the resources that are going to be deployed using those linked templates.

Based on the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates?tabs=azure-powershell#securing-an-external-template), the SharedTemplateSAS variable parameters will be below format

```
uri": "[concat(uri(deployment().properties.templateLink.uri, 'helloworld.json'), parameters('containerSasToken'))]",
```

Wherein `helloworld.json` is the linked template which is stored in the storage account inorder to avoid the public access to that template.

if you are working with Template spec securely,template spec stores the main template and its linked templates as a resource in your Azure subscription. You use Azure RBAC to grant access to users who need to deploy the template.

You can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-specs?tabs=azure-powershell#create-a-template-spec-with-linked-templates) documentation, if you want to create a template spec with link template & to deploy template spec as linked template.